# Matlab Classification load dataset

Tags: matlab, dataset

I am trying to load and use a dataset in order to run some algorithms(Neural Networks) in Matlab. I've downloaded a dataset from the internet which has instances and attributes.
I've saved that dataset as a plain text file, and also with the extension .data or .mat. But I am not able to import and use it in Matlab. 
How should I do? I also have to define a training and a test set after.
Thank you in advance.
I have to mention I am new to Matlab and trying to study it as a hobby.

Comment: Can you post a link to the data? How you read it into matlab will depend on the format. `dlmread` is a good first bet but you could also take a look at the data import wizard: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/recommended-methods-for-importing-data.html?refresh=true. Lastly, Matlab does come with it's own data sets too: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/_bq9uxn4.html, the fischer-iris set is quite popular for these sorts of applications.

Comment: Here it is the link http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine . Also, I'm not sure how could I create the training and the test set.

Comment: [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) will handle inputting your `wine.data`. Spiltting into sets is a simple task using the `:` operator. You should elaborate on exactly what it is you are stuck on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just load the data by:

```
data = load('wine.data');
```

Then, you can split the data to training and testing very easily.
Here, I put 70% data for training and 30% for testing, but you could choose other fraction. 60-40 or 80-20

```
data = data(randperm(end), :);

traindata = data(1:floor(0.7*size(data, 1)), :);
testdata = data(floor(0.7*size(data, 1))+1:end, :);
```

In the end, when you want to run the classifier, remember that in this dataset, the first column is the label and the rest are features.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You should explain the threshold of where exactly you are splitting your data.  It looks like you are choosing 70% of the data as training and 30% as testing, but this would not be obvious to a novice programmer.  I suggest placing this information into your post.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer.